# WPF IValueConverter for DateTime grid field

Tags: wpf, ivalueconverter

I have a xamDataGrid where I read in data from a file. This field is of type datetime. I would like to change the foreground color of this column when the date loaded is greater than todays date. I have a following IValueConverter:

```
    public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {

            if (value != null)
            {
                var color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

                int result = DateTime.Compare((DateTime)value, todaysDate);

                if (result > 0)
                    return color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                else
                    return color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            }

            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

I get and error from this: (DateTime)value

When I step through the code it seems that the if (value !=null) is executed even though there is no data being displayed in the datagrid. Not sure why this is in this path. It should only be executed when I'm loading a file into the datagrid.

Here is the xaml:

```
        <viewModel:MyConverter x:Key="myDateConv"/>




                                   <igDP:UnboundField Name="My Date" BindingPath="MyDate" Width="Auto" BindingMode="TwoWay" >
                                            <igDP:UnboundField.Settings>
                                            <igDP:FieldSettings AllowEdit="True" >
                                                <igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>
                                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamDateTimeEditor}" >
                                                        <Setter Property="Mask" Value="mm/dd/yyyy" />
                                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},Converter={StaticResource myDateConv}}"/>
                                                    </Style>
                                                </igDP:FieldSettings.EditorStyle>

                                            </igDP:FieldSettings>
                                        </igDP:UnboundField.Settings>
                                    </igDP:UnboundField>
```

here is the class:

```
   public class myPrice : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {


        private DateTime myDate;
        public DateTime MyDate
        {
            get { return myDate; }
            set
            {
                if (myDate != value)
                {
                    priceDate = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("MyDate");
                }
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)

                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: As a note, the local variable `color` in the Convert method is totally redundant. Just write `return result > 0 ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.White;`.

Comment: Besides that, if `(DateTime)value` throws an InvalidCastException, `value` is obviously not a DateTime, hence the Binding's source property is not a DateTime.

Comment: Here is a snippet of the binding class which is DateTime

'''
 private DateTime myDate;
        public DateTime MyDate
        {
            get { return myDate; }
            set
            {
                if (myDate != value)
                {
                    myDate = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("MyDate");
                }
            }
        }
'''

Comment: How do I add properly formatted code to a comment? I would like to add my xaml as well?

Comment: Edit the question...

Comment: @Halo: What's the value of `value` when you debug?

Comment: You are setting `priceDate = value;` instead of `myDate = value;` in your setter.

Comment: No idea how this UnboundField stuff is supposed to work, but using `{RelativeSource Self}` in a XamDateTimeEditor Style obviously means that the Binding source is a XamDateTimeEditor instance (which is obviously not a DataTime).

Comment: The xamDateTimeEditor is an Infragistics reference. I'm not sure what to change this to, do you? anyone have any Infragistics experience?